# subView's touchesBegan: withEvent: selector not called

Tags: iphone, uiview, touch-event

In the following code, I created a `MTLabel` object and a `UIButton` object, changed their frame, then add `UIButton` as subView of 'MTLabel'

```
MTLabel* label = [MTLabel labelWithTitle:title];
label.frame = ...
UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[rightButton addTarget:self
                action:@selector(didSelectStore:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
[label addSubview:rightButton];
rightButton.frame = ...;
[an addLabel:label];
```

After that both `UIView`s appears on screen, however`didSelectStore:` is never called when touching that `rightButton`.

As `MTLabel` is defined in a third-party lib, I don't have it's source code. So I write a category like this:

```
@implementation MTLabel(button)
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
......
@end
```

After doing that, `[rightButton touchesBegan:event:]` is still not called, not mention that action.

So the touch events are not working as expected in that subView.

Any idea on how then happen and what should I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to create a category and add `touchesBegan`: to make this work. Have you ensured that `label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`?